# Retrieve Page Numbers From PDF Bookmarks?

Tags: vba, pdf, adobe

I have written a code in VBA to print specified page numbers of a PDF document. I am trying to find a way to retrieve the page number and name of each PDF bookmark so that I can plug the data into Excel and print. I have multiple multiple PDF files in which the report number itself is the bookmark. I have not been able to acccess the bookmark via VBA. However, I have been able to search the documents and return a page number into Excel. This is time consuming because all the PDFs are saved as an image and must be converted. I am pretty good with VBA, but I have zero experience with Java script. I have also tried splitting the files by Top Level bookmark with no success. The files save as the wrong bookmark name. Can anyone provide a solution?

```
Public Sub PrintPDFPartial(strFileName As String, intBeginPage As Integer, 
intEndPage As Integer)

'This works but requires Adobe Acrobat Standard
Dim AcroApp As AcroApp
Dim AcroAVDoc As AcroAVDoc
Dim AcroPDDoc As AcroPDDoc
Set AcroApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
Set AcroAVDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")
Const POSTSCRIPT_LEVEL = 2
If AcroAVDoc.Open(strFileName, vbNull) <> True Then
    Exit Sub
End If
Set AcroAVDoc = AcroApp.GetActiveDoc
Set AcroPDDoc = AcroAVDoc.GetPDDoc
AcroAVDoc.printPages intBeginPage - 1, intEndPage - 1, POSTSCRIPT_LEVEL, 
True, False
AcroAVDoc.Close True
AcroApp.Exit
Set AcroDoc = Nothing
Set AcroApp = Nothing

End Sub


Sub Printpartial()

Dim strFileName As String
Dim intBeginPage As Integer, intEndPage As Integer, pPage As Integer
weld = Range("Weld").Column
lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, weld).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 5 To lrow

search = Cells(i, weld)
FileType = Range("FileType")
report = Range("SearchFor").Column
iName = Cells(i, report)
Filepath = Range("File_Path")
pPage = Range("N" & i)

strFileName = (Filepath & iName & "." & FileType)
intBeginPage = pPage

intEndPage = pPage

Call PrintPDFPartial(strFileName, pPage, pPage)
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Always helps to include the code in your question, please [edit], thanks.

Comment: What exactly does this have to do with Javascript?

Comment: Ben, I don't have any code to add. I am looking for suggestions. None of the VBA directly relates to my question. I can still add if you would like.

Comment: Google results mentioned js code. I don't anything about it.

Comment: What "I have written a code in VBA" should mean?

Comment: What data structure do you have (and can you share an example?) and what do you want to output (and can you share an example?) I'm not sure this is clear from the original wording of the question.

Comment: Just added my code to print. It take a number from column "N" and prints the page "#" from the PDF. I need some way to pull the name of each bookmark and it's page number from a PDF. I don't think I can do that with VBA so I'm looking for other solutions.